# Is MS Office necessary when using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB provider?

Tags: excel, vb6, oledb

I am trying to read an excel file an can do it using ADO.
My question is, do I need to have office installed when reading an excel file using the Jet.OLEDB Provider?

Currently I'm only testing on pcs that have office installed, that's why I'm asking.Programming language in concern is VB6.

Thanks.

Comment: You should try to use the newer `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider if you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you won't need to have office installed, but you will need to have MDAC/WDAC (which contains Jet) installed. On newer operating systems, this is part of the OS. On older OS's (Win 95/98/possibly even 2000), you needed to run an MDAC installer.

Answer (score 1):

No - The Jet driver is used for reading any form of DB files from text files to Excel to Access and is offered my Microsoft independantly of Office.